# How to make validation work on scrollable form

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I created the following scrollable quiz with an entry form as the last section:
http://jsfiddle.net/baumdexterous/xsWz5/

I want validation to occur, but for some reason it only works on the first question (try to click next without selecting one of the radio options) but not on the rest of the questions. Also, the validation doesn't work on the fields in the last section (entry form).

Any idea how I can make the validation work across all sections? Thanks so much.

```
<div id="drawer">
  Please complete all the required fields.
</div>


<div id="main">

    <!-- the form -->
    <form action="http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/wizard.htm#">

      <div id="wizard">
        <ul id="status">
          <li class="active" style="margin-left: -5px;"><p>1</p></li>
          <li style="margin-left: 56px;"><p>2</p></li>
          <li style="margin-left: 56px;"><p>3</p></li>
          <li style="margin-left: 56px;"><p>4</p></li>
          <li style="margin-left: 56px;"><p>5</p></li>
          <li style="margin-left: 56px;"><p>6</p></li>
          <li style="margin-left: 56px;"><p>7</p></li>
          <li style="margin-left: 56px;"><p>8</p></li>
          <li style="margin-left: 63px;"><p>Entry <br />Form</p></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="items">

            <!-- Question 1 -->
            <div class="page one">
                <h1>1</h1>
                <p>Question 1</p>
                <ul>
                    <li class="required double">
                            <div class="qselections orio required">
                                <p><input type="radio" value="a" name="question1" data-type="false">a) Answer (wrong)</p>
                                <p><input type="radio" value="b" name="question1" data-type="false">b) Answer (wrong)</p>
                                <p><input type="radio" value="c" name="question1" data-type="true">c) Answer (right)</p>
                                <div class="content content-false">Incorrect: The correct answer is C.</div>
                                <div class="content content-true">Correct</div>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <li class="clearfix">
                    <button type="button" class="next right">Next</button>
                </li>
            </div>

            <!-- Question 2 -->
            <div class="page two">
                <h1>2</h1>
                <p>Question 2</p>
                <ul>
                    <li class="required double">
                            <div class="qselections orio required">
                                <p><input type="radio" value="a" name="question1" data-type="false">a) Answer (wrong)</p>
                                <p><input type="radio" value="b" name="question1" data-type="false">b) Answer (wrong)</p>
                                <p><input type="radio" value="c" name="question1" data-type="true">c) Answer (right)</p>
                                <div class="content content-false">Incorrect: The correct answer is C.</div>
                                <div class="content content-true">Correct</div>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <li class="clearfix">
                    <button type="button" class="next right">Next</button>
                </li>
            </div>

            <!-- Question 3 -->
            <div class="page three">
                <h1>3</h1>
                <p>Question 3</p>
                <ul>
                    <li class="required double">
                            <div class="qselections orio required">
                                <p><input type="radio" value="a" name="question1" data-type="false">a) Answer (wrong)</p>
                                <p><input type="radio" value="b" name="question1" data-type="false">b) Answer (wrong)</p>
                                <p><input type="radio" value="c" name="question1" data-type="true">c) Answer (right)</p>
                                <div class="content content-false">Incorrect: The correct answer is C.</div>
                                <div class="content content-true">Correct</div>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <li class="clearfix">
                    <button type="button" class="next right">Next</button>
                </li>
            </div>

            <!-- Question 4 -->
            <div class="page four">
                <h1>4</h1>
                <p>Question 4</p>
                <ul>
                    <li class="required double">
                            <div class="qselections orio required">
                                <p><input type="radio" value="a" name="question1" data-type="false">a) Answer (wrong)</p>
                                <p><input type="radio" value="b" name="question1" data-type="false">b) Answer (wrong)</p>
                                <p><input type="radio" value="c" name="question1" data-type="true">c) Answer (right)</p>
                                <div class="content content-false">Incorrect: The correct answer is C.</div>
                                <div class="content content-true">Correct</div>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <li class="clearfix">
                    <button type="button" class="next right">Next</button>
                </li>
            </div>

            <!-- Question 5 -->
            <div class="page five">
                <h1>5</h1>
                <p>Question 5</p>
                <ul>
                    <li class="required double">
                            <div class="qselections orio required">
                                <p><input type="radio" value="a" name="question1" data-type="false">a) Answer (wrong)</p>
                                <p><input type="radio" value="b" name="question1" data-type="false">b) Answer (wrong)</p>
                                <p><input type="radio" value="c" name="question1" data-type="true">c) Answer (right)</p>
                                <div class="content content-false">Incorrect: The correct answer is C.</div>
                                <div class="content content-true">Correct</div>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <li class="clearfix">
                    <button type="button" class="next right">Next</button>
                </li>
            </div>

            <!-- Question 6 -->
            <div class="page six">
                <h1>6</h1>
                <p>Question 6</p>
                <ul>
                    <li class="required double">
                            <div class="qselections orio required">
                                <p><input type="radio" value="a" name="question1" data-type="false">a) Answer (wrong)</p>
                                <p><input type="radio" value="b" name="question1" data-type="false">b) Answer (wrong)</p>
                                <p><input type="radio" value="c" name="question1" data-type="true">c) Answer (right)</p>
                                <div class="content content-false">Incorrect: The correct answer is C.</div>
                                <div class="content content-true">Correct</div>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <li class="clearfix">
                    <button type="button" class="next right">Next</button>
                </li>
            </div>

            <!-- Question 7 -->
            <div class="page seven">
                <h1>7</h1>
                <p>Question 7</p>
                <ul>
                    <li class="required double">
                            <div class="qselections orio required">
                                <p><input type="radio" value="a" name="question1" data-type="false">a) Answer (wrong)</p>
                                <p><input type="radio" value="b" name="question1" data-type="false">b) Answer (wrong)</p>
                                <p><input type="radio" value="c" name="question1" data-type="true">c) Answer (right)</p>
                                <div class="content content-false">Incorrect: The correct answer is C.</div>
                                <div class="content content-true">Correct</div>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <li class="clearfix">
                    <button type="button" class="next right">Next</button>
                </li>
            </div>

            <!-- Question 8 -->
            <div class="page eight">
                <h1>8</h1>
                <p>Question 8</p>
                <ul>
                    <li class="required double">
                            <div class="qselections orio required">
                                <p><input type="radio" value="a" name="question1" data-type="false">a) Answer (wrong)</p>
                                <p><input type="radio" value="b" name="question1" data-type="false">b) Answer (wrong)</p>
                                <p><input type="radio" value="c" name="question1" data-type="true">c) Answer (right)</p>
                                <div class="content content-false">Incorrect: The correct answer is C.</div>
                                <div class="content content-true">Correct</div>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <li class="clearfix">
                    <button type="button" class="next right">Next</button>
                </li>
            </div>


          <!-- page3 -->
          <div class="page" style="background:white">

        <h2>
          <strong>Step 2: </strong> Contact Information <b></b>
          <em>Please tell us where you live:</em>
        </h2>

        <ul>
          <!-- address -->
          <li class="required">
            <label>
              <strong>1.</strong>
                  Enter Your Street Address <span>*</span><br>
              <input type="text" class="text" name="email">
              <em><strong>Example</strong>: Random Street 69 A 666</em>
            </label>
          </li>

          <!-- zip / city -->
          <li class="required double">

            <label>
              <strong>2.</strong> Enter Your Zip Code <span>*</span><br>
              <input class="text" name="zip">
              <em>This must be a numeric value</em>
            </label>

            <label>
              <strong>3.</strong> and The City <span>*</span>
              <select name="city">
            <option value="">-- please select --</option>
            <option>Helsinki</option>
            <option>Berlin</option>
            <option>New York</option>
              </select>
            </label>
          </li>

          <li class="clearfix">
            <button type="button" class="next right">
                  Next
                </button>
          </li>

          <br clear="all">
        </ul>

          </div>

          <!-- page4 -->
          <div class="page">

        <h2>
          <strong>Step 3: </strong> Congratulations! <b></b>
          <em>You are now a happy member of the Open Source community</em>
        </h2>


        <img src="http://jquerytools.org/media/img/title/eye.png" style="margin:30px 0 0 140px">


          </div>

        </div><!--items-->

      </div><!--wizard-->

    </form>


</div> <!-- end wrapper -->
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
 $(function () {



      var root = $("#wizard").scrollable();
      var isRadioCheck = false;
      // some variables that we need
      var api = root.scrollable(),
          drawer = $("#drawer");

          // prevent the user from making another selection once one radio option has been selected
                $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
                    var name = $(this).attr("name");
                    $("input[name=" + name + "]").prop("disabled", true);
                });
          // Show user correct answer

        $(function () {
            $('.orio').each(function (i) {
                var $row = $(this);
                var $radios = $row.find('input');
                $radios.attr('name', 'group-' + i);
                $radios.on('change', function () {
                    var type = $(this).attr('data-type');
                    $row
                        .find('.content').hide()
                        .filter('.content-' + type)
                            .show();
                });

            });
        });

      // validation logic is done inside the onBeforeSeek callback
      api.onBeforeSeek(function (event, i) {

          // we are going 1 step backwards so no need for validation
          if (api.getIndex() < i || $('input[type=radio]').is(':checked')) {

              // 1. get current page
              var page = root.find(".page,.qselections").eq(api.getIndex()),

                  // 2. .. and all required fields inside the page
                  inputs = page.find(".required :input").removeClass("error"),

                  // 3. .. which are empty
                  empty = inputs.filter(function () {
                      isRadioCheck = $('input[type=radio]').is(':checked');
                      return $(this).val().replace(/\s*/g, '') == '';
                  });



              //ealert('Empty Value is bool : ' + empty.length + isRadioCheck);
              if (isRadioCheck) {
                  $('.qselections').removeClass("error");
                  //alert('removed');
              }
              // if there are empty fields, then
              if (empty.length || !isRadioCheck) {

                  // slide down the drawer
                  drawer.slideDown(function () {

                      // colored flash effect
                      drawer.css("backgroundColor", "#fff");
                      setTimeout(function () {
                          drawer.css("backgroundColor", "#fff");
                      }, 1000);
                  });

                  // add a CSS class name "error" for empty & required fields
                  empty.addClass("error");
                  if (!isRadioCheck) $('.qselections').addClass("error");
                  // cancel seeking of the scrollable by returning false
                  return false;

                  // everything is good
              } else {

                  // hide the drawer
                  drawer.slideUp();
              }

          }

          // update status bar
          $("#status li").removeClass("active").eq(i).addClass("active");

      });

      // if tab is pressed on the next button seek to next page
      root.find("button.next").keydown(function (e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 9) {

              // seeks to next tab by executing our validation routine
              api.next();
              e.preventDefault();
          }
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend helped me solve this. Here is the solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/baumdexterous/ejRxs/

He made a lot of changes in the onBeforeSeek method, getting rid of the parallel assignment
and changing the way it was selecting tags (and did away with the 'empty' selector entirely). Thanks!

Updated JavaScript:

```
 $(function () {



      var root = $("#wizard").scrollable();
      var isRadioCheck = false;
      // some variables that we need
      var api = root.scrollable(),
          drawer = $("#drawer");

          // prevent the user from making another selection once one radio option has been selected
                $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
                    var name = $(this).attr("name");
                    $("input[name=" + name + "]").prop("disabled", true);
                });
          // Show user correct answer

        $(function () {
            $('.orio').each(function (i) {
                var $row = $(this);
                var $radios = $row.find('input');
                $radios.attr('name', 'group-' + i);
                $radios.on('change', function () {
                    var type = $(this).attr('data-type');
                    $row
                        .find('.content').hide()
                        .filter('.content-' + type)
                            .show();
                });

            });
        });

      // validation logic is done inside the onBeforeSeek callback
      api.onBeforeSeek(function (event, i) {

          // we are going 1 step backwards so no need for validation
          if (api.getIndex() < i || $('input[type=radio]').is(':checked')) {

              // 1. get current page
              var page = root.find(".page").eq(api.getIndex());

              // 2. .. and all required fields inside the page
              var inputs = page.find(".required input");

              var isRadioCheck = inputs.is(':checked');

              //ealert('Empty Value is bool : ' + empty.length + isRadioCheck);
              if (isRadioCheck) {
                  $('.qselections').removeClass("error");
                  //alert('removed');
              }
              // if there are empty fields, then
              if (!isRadioCheck) {

                  // slide down the drawer
                  drawer.slideDown(function () {

                      // colored flash effect
                      drawer.css("backgroundColor", "#fff");
                      setTimeout(function () {
                          drawer.css("backgroundColor", "#fff");
                      }, 1000);
                  });

                  // add a CSS class name "error" for empty & required fields
                  inputs.addClass("error");
                  if (!isRadioCheck) $('.qselections').addClass("error");
                  // cancel seeking of the scrollable by returning false
                  return false;

                  // everything is good
              } else {

                  // hide the drawer
                  drawer.slideUp();
              }

          }

          // update status bar
          $("#status li").removeClass("active").eq(i).addClass("active");

      });

      // if tab is pressed on the next button seek to next page
      root.find("button.next").keydown(function (e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 9) {

              // seeks to next tab by executing our validation routine
              api.next();
              e.preventDefault();
          }
      });
  });
```